# Insert into database in OOP doesn't work

Tags: php, database, oop, object, insert

I'm trying to make object oriented login and insert into database, following tutorial but this doesn't work. It won't make connection to database, error: No database selected. Can you help me?

This is code:

form in index.php

```
   <form action="insert.php" method="post">
   Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>
   Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br>
   <input type="submit" />
```

Class in insert_class.php:

```
<?php 
class Insert_class {

public $servername;
public $username;
public $password;
public $dbname;

public function __construct(){

 // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 // insert into database
 $sql = "INSERT INTO nametable (firstname, lastname)
 VALUES ('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]')";

 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
 }

  mysqli_close($conn);

  }
}
```

Object for login and insert in database in insert.php:

```
require 'insert_class.php';

$insert = new Insert_class();

$insert->servername ='localhost';
$insert->username ='root';
$insert->password ='';
$insert->dbname ='newdatabase';
```

Comment: Please learn how to access a class property, this is PHP 101. Also you should get many errors, so turn on error reporting

Comment: I'm researching this for 3 days. If variables are added in insert_class.php insert into database works good. Problem is why variables from object doesn't apply?

Comment: As I said you need to learn the basics: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: You are connecting to the DB in the `_construct()` function. That method gets run as soon as you do `$insert = new Insert_class();` But at that point you have not set the objects properties that the constructor needs.

Comment: Yes, there are notices for undefined variables. I know that. Isn't this correct way for accessing class property?$insert->servername ='localhost';

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the same error is even if properties are added above $insert = new Insert_class();

Comment: @Rizier123 what do you mean with "PHP 101"?

Comment: You cannot do that, as you have not instantiated the object from the class yet

Comment: @messerbill The introduction courses in college and in university's have the number 101.

Comment: @Rizier123 ah tank you :D in germany i never noticed smth like that, which not means that its not existent in germany xD

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I understand. If I change function in any other name (to not to be__construct) there is blank page only as result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 
class Insert_class {

    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;
    private $con

    public function __construct($servername,$username,$password,$dbname)
    {

        $this->servername = $servername;
        $this->username   = $username;
        $this->password   = $password;
        $this->dbname     = $dbname;
        // Create connection
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->servername, $this->username,
                                     $this->password, $this->dbname);

        if ($this->con->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $this->con->connect_errno . ') '. $this->con->connect_error);
        }

        // etc

    }
```

Then you can do

```
require 'insert_class.php';
$insert = new Insert_class('localhost','root','','newdatabase');
```

Notice I also captured the $con as a property. Your code would have lots it as it would only have been visible in __construct but none of the other methods you may want to write in this class.

Also Notice I changed the test for a successful connection. This is the correct way to check if a connection was successful. a simple `if( ! $con )` is not good enough.

Comment: I was actually going to do that, that was my first solution. But then I thought OP would like a little bit simplicity. My solution works as well buddy ;) +1.

Comment: This gives "connected" message as example above. I thing both work for connecting but now I need to manage inserting part of code.

Comment: The connection test in your code was not correct, see the change to that in the answer

Comment: @Akshay  All I can think of is that on your system you must have these parameters all set in your PHP.INI file `mysqli.default_pw` and `mysqli.default_user` and `mysqli.default_host =` which would explain why that code worked on your system. But thats not a good system to be testing database connection code on for obvious reasons

Answer (score 0):

Rather than defining the connection details explicitly ,you can use DEFINE ..

```
  define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
  define("DB_USER", "root");
  define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
  define("DB_NAME", "newdatabase");
```

**insert_class.php** ...

```
public function __construct(){

  $conn  = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: This would make it impossible to re-use the same class for a different database, making it more 'class oriented programming' instead of 'object oriented programming'.